# Passing a local static array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, static

I'm trying to pass a local array from a function `letter_remover`, which reads an original array, removes vowels + h, w and y, then copies that into a new array. This new array is then passed to main.

For example input `plutonium` would become `pltnm`. However when I call the function in main and print out the new array, it will duplicate some letters, for instance `plltnm` is printed.

```
void array_filler (char a[]);
char * letter_remover (char b[]);

int main (void)

{
char name[MAX];
char *p;
int i;
array_filler(name);
p = letter_remover(name);
printf("Local array passed back: ");
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
    printf("%s", p);
    p++;
    }

return 0; 

}
```

If I print the new array created in the function `letter_remover`, it prints correctly. The letter_remover function creates the new array as a static char[] array and returns a char *

array_filler contains:

```
void array_filler (char a[])

{
printf("Type name: ");
int i = 0, c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        c = tolower(c);
        if (isalpha(c))
            {
                a[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
    }
a[i] = '\0';
printf("Name inside array: %s\n", a);

}
```

letter_remover contains:

```
char * letter_remover (char b[])

{

int i;
static char c[MAX];
char a[] = "aeiouywh";
printf("Name without forbidden characters: ");
for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (!strchr(a, b[i]))
    {
        c[i] = b[i];
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
}
c[i] = '\0';
printf("\n");
return c;
}
```

Comment: What is "local arrray"?

Comment: What are the contents of `array_filler` and `letter_remover`?

Comment: @MikeCAT It is already a static array

Comment: @dbush I have added their contents now.

Comment: The `for` loop in the `main` function seems strange.Why don't you print `p` only once?

Comment: I dont think variable "c" is created everytime. this is c. so if you want to create "new" array. you have to use "malloc"

Comment: @MikeCAT If I print p only once it prints nothing

Comment: The `letter_remover` functin may not work well. You should have separate counter for input and output positions.

Comment: simplest solution to fix your code, remove "static" from "c". then , use "return strdup(c)" instead of "return c"

Comment: You should give your variables more intuitive names, rather than some one letter ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main, you probably want to say

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
    printf("%c", p[i]);
    p++;
    }
```

In order to print each char in p. Since this will output beyond the 0 char, a better way would be to simply say `printf("%s", p);`, without a loop. Or just `printf(p);` if you trust the string! Or `puts(p);` which would apparently print a newline as well, which is most likely desirable for a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Your array index, into c, increases every time you go around the loop...instead you only need to change the index to c, when you actually copy a legal character.

```
for (j = 0, i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (!strchr(a, b[i]))
    {
        c[j] = b[i];
        j++;
        printf("%c", c[j]);
    }
}
c[j] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is here, in `letter_remover`:

```
for (i = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (!strchr(a, b[i]))
    {
        c[i] = b[i];
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
}
c[i] = '\0';
```

You're using the same index for `b` and `c`.  So at the end of the loop `c` contains NULL bytes at the spots where a letter is removed (because the array is static, it is initialized to all zeros).  You need to use a separate index for `c` when you write to it:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; b[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (!strchr(a, b[i]))
    {
        c[j] = b[i];
        printf("%c", c[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
c[j] = '\0';
```

Then `main` where you're printing the result:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    printf("%s", p);
    p++;
}
```

You're printing out the complete string repeatedly starting at each character.  So the first time through it print "pl" before it hits a NULL bytes, the the next time it starts at the "l" and prints that again before it hits the NULL byte, and so on.

Once you apply the first fix, all you need to do is print it once:

```
printf("%s", p);
```